# Flutter & Provider Auto Login

Tags: flutter, provider

So I'm trying to setup auto login with Provider and through Consumer but the problem I'm having is that the Page isn't updating. I'm guessing because it's passing the same widget so it's not changing it but I don't know how to fix it...

Update:

So When I login or logout it remains on the same page even though the console shows that the log in the consumer is being called, I think the only time it works it in the initial launch of the app if the user is logged in or not

Code:

```
Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  List<CameraDescription> cameras = await availableCameras();

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeProvider>(
          create: (_) => ThemeProvider(Themes.light),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<CameraProvider>(
          create: (_) => CameraProvider(cameras),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<NetworkProvider>(
          create: (_) => NetworkProvider.instance(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<UserProvider>(
          create: (_) => UserProvider.instance(),
        ),
      ],
      child: DevicePreview(
        builder: (context) => App(
          page: Consumer4<ThemeProvider, CameraProvider, NetworkProvider, UserProvider>(
            builder: (context, theme, camera, network, user, child) {
              Funcs.logger('Consumer: ${user.status}');

              return user.status == UserStatus.Null
                  ? LoadingPage(text: 'Loading...')
                  : user.status == UserStatus.Unauthenticated
                      ? WelcomePage()
                      : user.status == UserStatus.Authenticated
                          ? user.user.isEmployer ? EmployerPage() : SeekerPage()
                          : LoadingPage(text: 'Loading...');
            },
          ),
        ),
        enabled: (await Funcs.isPhysicalDevice()),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget page;

  const App({Key key, this.page}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Platform.isIOS
      ? CupertinoApp(
          home: this.page,
          theme: Utils.currentTheme(context: context).cupertinoOverrideTheme,
          navigatorObservers: [
            Services().analytics.firebaseAnalyticsObserver,
          ],
          title: Constants.title,
          localizationsDelegates: const <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
            DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        )
      : MaterialApp(
          home: this.page,
          theme: Utils.currentTheme(context: context),
          navigatorObservers: [
            Services().analytics.firebaseAnalyticsObserver,
          ],
          title: Constants.title,
          localizationsDelegates: const <LocalizationsDelegate<dynamic>>[
            DefaultMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
            DefaultWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          ],
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );
}
```

user_provider.dart

```
enum UserStatus { Null, Authenticated, Authenticating, Unauthenticated, Unauthenticating }

class UserProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  var _auth;
  User _user;
  UserStatus _status = UserStatus.Null;

  UserProvider.instance() : _auth = Services().auth.auth {
    _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(
      (u) async {
        if (u != null) {
          if (await APIs().users.userExists(userID: u.uid))
            Funcs.logger('if');
            await APIs().users.user(userID: u.uid).then((user) {
              this.user = user;
              this.status = UserStatus.Authenticated;
              return null;
            });
        } else {
          Funcs.logger('else');
          this.user = null;
          this.status = UserStatus.Unauthenticated;
        }

        notifyListeners();
      },
    );
  }

  get auth => this._auth;
  User get user => this._user;
  UserStatus get status => _status;

  set user(User value) {
    this._user = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  set status(UserStatus value) {
    _status = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future verify({
    String phoneNumber,
    int forceResendingToken,
    Future<Function> verificationCompleted(AuthCredential ac),
    Future<Function> onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout(String vID),
    Future<Function> onCodeSent(String vID, int code),
    Function verificationFailed(e),
  }) async {
    try {
      await Services().auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
          forceResendingToken: forceResendingToken,
          verificationCompleted: (ac) async => await verificationCompleted(ac),
          onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (vID) async => await onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout(vID),
          onCodeSent: (vID, code) async => await onCodeSent(vID, code),
          verificationFailed: verificationFailed);
    } catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<String> loginWithPhone({String vID, String smsCode}) async {
    try {
      this.status = UserStatus.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();

      return (await Services().auth.loginWithPhone(
                vID: vID,
                smsCode: smsCode,
                onFailure: (e) => Funcs.logger(e),
              ))
          .user
          .uid;
    } catch (e) {
      this.status = UserStatus.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();

      return null;
    }
  }

  Future<String> loginWithAuthCredential({AuthCredential ac}) async {
    try {
      this.status = UserStatus.Authenticating;
      notifyListeners();

      return (await Services().auth.loginWithAuthCredential(
                ac: ac,
                onFailure: (e) => Funcs.logger(e),
              ))
          .user
          .uid;
    } catch (e) {
      this.status = UserStatus.Unauthenticated;
      notifyListeners();

      return null;
    }
  }

  Future logout() async {
    this.status = UserStatus.Unauthenticating;
    notifyListeners();

    await Services().auth.logout();

    this.status = UserStatus.Unauthenticated;
    notifyListeners();

    return Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
  }
}


Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86...
Restarted application in 3,417ms.
I/flutter ( 6497): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #0   Funcs.logger (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:200:38)
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #1   main.().() (package:shaqay/main.dart:37:21)
I/flutter ( 6497): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6497): │  Consumer: UserStatus.Null
I/flutter ( 6497): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
W/FA      ( 6497): setCurrentScreen cannot be called with the same class and name
I/flutter ( 6497): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #0   Funcs.logger (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:200:38)
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #1   new UserProvider.instance.() (package:shaqay/backend/providers/user_provider.dart:25:17)
I/flutter ( 6497): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6497): │  else
I/flutter ( 6497): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #0   Funcs.logger (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:200:38)
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #1   main.().() (package:shaqay/main.dart:37:21)
I/flutter ( 6497): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6497): │  Consumer: UserStatus.Unauthenticated
I/flutter ( 6497): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #0   Funcs.logger (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:200:38)
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #1   main.().() (package:shaqay/main.dart:37:21)
I/flutter ( 6497): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6497): │  Consumer: UserStatus.Unauthenticated
I/flutter ( 6497): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #0   Funcs.logger (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:200:38)
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #1   main.().() (package:shaqay/main.dart:37:21)
I/flutter ( 6497): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6497): │  Consumer: UserStatus.Unauthenticated
I/flutter ( 6497): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 6497): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@160e295
I/flutter ( 6497): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #0   Funcs.logger (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:200:38)
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #1   _LoginPageState._mobile.().() (package:shaqay/frontend/pages/auth/login_page.dart:123:35)
I/flutter ( 6497): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6497): │  CODE SENT
I/flutter ( 6497): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): IF YOU WANT TO USE COLOR FILL FOR EACH CELL THEN SET enableActiveFill = true
I/BiChannelGoogleApi( 6497): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzaq@160e295
I/flutter ( 6497): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #0   Funcs.logger (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:200:38)
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #1   main.().() (package:shaqay/main.dart:37:21)
I/flutter ( 6497): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6497): │  Consumer: UserStatus.Authenticating
I/flutter ( 6497): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
D/FirebaseAuth( 6497): Notifying id token listeners about user ( uDjugkETzsTWbQZIDf7XFxenE7v1 ).
D/FirebaseAuth( 6497): Notifying auth state listeners about user ( uDjugkETzsTWbQZIDf7XFxenE7v1 ).
I/flutter ( 6497): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #0   Funcs.logger (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:200:38)
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #1   new UserProvider.instance.() (package:shaqay/backend/providers/user_provider.dart:18:19)
I/flutter ( 6497): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6497): │  if
I/flutter ( 6497): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #0   Funcs.logger (package:shaqay/frontend/configs/funcs.dart:200:38)
I/flutter ( 6497): │ #1   main.().() (package:shaqay/main.dart:37:21)
I/flutter ( 6497): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter ( 6497): │  Consumer: UserStatus.Authenticated
I/flutter ( 6497): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Comment: are you calling ```notifyListeners();``` on your ```status``` & ```isEmployer``` variables in the appropriate places

Comment: Yeah, I'm logging the changes under the consumer widget but it doesn't work, i have to hot restart for the change to occur.

Comment: can you post the relevant part of your  user class

Comment: Code is updated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post my setup and maybe it'll help you to be honest your setup is very similar to mine main differences I see are I have a `NotificationListener`  wrapped around my `MaterialApp` I don't where you would put it because thats the other difference you have your setup one level higher and I don't think you can wrap it around `App`.

```
Consumer<Auth>(
        builder: (_, auth, __) => NotificationListener(
          child: MaterialApp(
            theme: ThemeData(bottomAppBarTheme: BottomAppBarTheme()),
            home: FutureBuilder(
              future:
                  Future.wait([auth.isEmailVerified(), auth.tryAutoLogin()]),
              builder: (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot authResultSnapshot) =>
                  authResultSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
                      ? authResultSnapshot.data[1]
                          ? authResultSnapshot.data[0]
                              ? Example()
                              : EmailVerification()
                          : LoginScreen()
                      : SplashScreen(),
            ),
```

Comment: Does the consumer have to be directly under the MultiProvider() widget or can it be anywhere? Like MultiProvider(child: App(child: Consumer(...),),); instead of MP(c: C(c: App(...)))??

Comment: Update: I rearranged it to put the Consumer() inside the App() but it's still won't update the ui, only until I hot restart then it updates. The only time it works is when it goes from Null to Either Authenticated or Unathenticated. After that the ui won't update when I Log in or Log out.

Comment: Did you try moving it one level down to your ```MaterialApp```

Comment: Yeah, I updated the code, the page is inside the MaterialApp/CupertinoApp so the Consumer is inside the MApp/CApp.